# Can't edit files in a laravel project due to file ownership issue

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I am having a bit problem understanding permissions in linux.

I have a laravel application, which is owned by the user `www-data` and the group`www-data`. 
Now if I go and make changes to the files of the folder I am asked for a password every time I make a change.

So I tried to own the directory, I ran the command :
`sudo chown -R ramesh:www-data /var/www/html/ijiar/`

Now, I can successfully edit the files. but when I run this application in the browser, it gives a 500 error due to permissions issue.

contents of  `/var/log/apache2/error.log` :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/ijiar/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/ijiar/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:14181

If I give ownership back to `www-data` user,
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/ijiar/`

the application opens in the browser but while editing the files, it asks for passwords.

I added the `ramesh` to the `www-data` group, and the user `www-data` to the `www-data` group, and then tried giving permissions by this :

`sudo chown -R ramesh:www-data /var/www/html/ijiar/` but no use.

and with

`sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/ijiar/`

Still does not work. 
Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: you should keep the ownership to www-data and add yourself to the group (useradd -g ramesh -G www-data)

Comment: I did that. as I mentioned earlier. still can't edit the files.

Comment: and useradd command does not work because I am an existing user, should I try `usermod -g ramesh -G www-data` ?